# action button after the second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button in my form. I need my form to be processed after the first click (or pressing Enter) on the button, and after that, if some conditions would be true, I do something like submitting the form by the second click or pressing Enter key on the button.

What do you think I have to do?

Comment: Please consider improving your question. Your question in its current form does not contain enough details. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section on ways to improve your question.

Comment: Assign a function to the entire submitting and say if true do this else do this. On click, set the function to true so on second function it will notice that its true and it will submit. Now on enter, say if keycode 13 pressed, submit form. If you have a http://jsfiddle.net or some code I will be able to show a preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a (boolean) variable that saves your state, which is set to true when the first click (or action) has happened and your condition is true. Then submit on the second action when the variable is true.

If the condition has to be matched on both clicks (I guess so) consider the following:

```
$(function() {
    var first = false;
    $("form").submit(function() {
        if(first && checkCondition())
            submit();
        if(!first && checkCondition())
            first = true;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so in basic code:

```
var answered = false;
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        if(answered == false) {
            answered = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you're trying to do correctly, you could bind an event handler to the `submit` event. That event handler will handle your validation, but if you use the jQuery [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method, it will only be executed once. The next time the `submit` event is triggered, the form will submit as usual:

```
$("yourForm").one("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Stop the form from being submitted
    //Do stuff
});
```

The result is effectively the same as @Manuel van Rijn's answer, but using jQuery's `one` just makes it a bit shorter and cleaner in my opinion. However, this could also add a slight performance benefit, as the event handler is unbound after it's execution and won't be called again.